# Why can't Hibernate tools in Eclipse find the OracleSpatial10gDialect class when I reverse engineer?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, hibernate-spatial

I added the hibernate-spatial dependency to my pom, and I can see the jar gets downloaded after I update the project. When I run the app it works fine using the spatial dialect, but when I try to reverse engineer in Eclipse it tells me

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect
```

I have the project that has the hibernate-spatial dependency set as the project in the hibernate console configuration. I can see that project's maven dependencies library listed under it in the console configuration classpath tab, and I can see the hibernate-spatial jar listed under that library in the classpath tab of that project's properties.

I even tried adding the hibernate spatial jar as an external jar to the classpath tab of the hibernate console configuration with no luck.